# Trying to use ergoemacs on Mac

Tags: osx, ergoemacs

I have been trying to get Ergoemacs working on Mac for about 2 weeks now and I have finally managed to get it working using a combo of:

- Ignoring Mac's supplied ancient build of Emacs
- Installing from Brew.

My final hurdle seems to be that the keyboard maps that comes with ITerm2 and Mac in general seems to be in loggerheads with those defined in Ergoemacs. I have looked at Aquamacs and they seem to come with another set of keyboard shortcuts. I would really hate to have to learn one set of keyboard shortcut during the time I work on Mac and the other times when I am on my Linux machine as that would really hurt my muscle memory.

Any suggestion?

Further digging indicated I need to change the key binding for Mac but the keybinding provided is only for Mac OS X. Any idea how to get it working on Yosemite or better yet how do I change the keybinding on Yosemite?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why can't you set the same bindings on all machines? Which bindings are those? If you use the same emacs init file at both places, the bindings should be identical. Are you trying to run emacs in terminal mode or GUI mode?

Comment: In ergo, M-i moves the cursor up. This is okay on Linux since M-i is not bound to any thing, while on ITerm it's bound to renaming the session, on Terminal it's bound to the inspector.

Comment: @LowKianSeong I'd recommend you to use a GUI Emacs on OS X.

Comment: @lunaryorn I have already installed aquamacs, but then as I said it comes with it's own set of keyboard mappings. If possible I would prefer just to learn one set.

Comment: Since you are fond of ITerm2 and *ergo-aqua*, either:  (1) Figure out how to redefine the iTerm2 keymappings that are in conflict with *ergo-aqua*; or, (2) create / choose keyboard mappings in *ergo-aqua* that do not conflict with iTerm2.  Of course, the OSX system keyboard shortcuts may also conflict and if so, you'll need to deal with that too.  Ergoemacs and Aquamacs are really for a finite group of individuals who like the way the authors have pre-configured everything.  If you find you don't like having others choose for you, then use http://emacsformacosx.com/ and configure it yourself.

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation for iTerm2 -- read the section about setting the keyboard shortcuts:  https://iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html#documentation-preferences.html OSX also has a System Preferences application (e.g., click on the apple in the menubar and select System Preferences), and inside the System Preferences pane it is an icon called Keyboard -- inside is a tab for *Keyboard Shortcuts* -- look at every keyboard shortcut that is defined within the *Keyboard Shortcuts* tab for each group and see if you like how it is configured -- if you don't like it, then change it.